# menu button Problem in tablet?

Tags: android

i create android application. it is compatible for android phones and tablet. but i problem occur in some tablet, in tablet no physical menu button. in my app all menu functionality added in device menu button. how to handle Menu Button event in Tablet? if yes how?.

please help me.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can open menu using **onClickListeners**.

For Example, if you have a `imageview` in that page, then you can open menu for image click event

```
    image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        openOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes ofcourse. If u can make a onClick to work. That's all it takes.

Comment: It is not working for me,in xoom tablet.Please let me know any reasons for taht.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken tablets draw the menu button to the right of "back", "home" and "apps" buttons.